# Render unique ng-transclude template for each ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to render unique template for each elements in directive? I would like to show what I am talking about. For example

```html
<div example-backgrounds images="['xyz.jpg','xyz2.jpg', 'xyz3.jpg','xyz4.jpg' ]" ><!-- directive then ng-repeat on each .jpg file -->
 <div><h1>Title</h1></div>    <!-- transclude for xyz.jpg -->
    <div><button>Title2</button></div>  <!-- transclude for xyz2.jpg -->
   <div><h2>Title3</h2></div>   <!-- transclude for xyz3.jpg -->
   <div><h2>Hello <button>Title4</button></h2></div>   <!-- transclude for xyz4.jpg -->
</div>
```

There are 4 .jpg files then I would like to render for each element other transclude. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Sure it's possible and there are numerous ways to do it. Please show what you have tried

Answer (score -1):

Okay i solved myself problem. There is my solution. Is it good? Somebody have better code? There is mine.

```js
    function link(scope, element, attr,ctrl,transclude) {
       var index = 0;
      transclude(function(clone){
        clone.each(function(v,k){
         
          if(this.nodeType === 3)
            return;
          var currentClone = this;
          $timeout(function(){
            $(element.find(".magic-bind")[index]).append(k);
            index++;
          })
        })
      })
    }
```

There is link function to example-backgrounds. Then we have correct output.